# Boolean interpolation on CABasicAnimation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I have a `UIButton` that I would like to use a `CABasicAnimation` to create a flashing effect using the highlight state of the button.  This is the code I am using to create this effect:

```
    let highlighted: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "highlighted")
    highlighted.fromValue = false
    highlighted.toValue = true
    highlighted.duration = 1.0
    highlighted.repeatCount = Float.infinity;
    highlighted.autoreverses = true

    myButton.layer.addAnimation(highlighted, forKey: "highlighted")
```

Now my understanding of this code is that it should go from fromValue of false to toValue of true and then back to fromValue of false in 1 second, and repeat this forever.  However, it seems the interpolation is not happening at all.  I tried looking at Apple Docs to see if interpolation can be done on boolean fields, but was unable to find any answer on this matter, so I am asking is it possible to do an animation with a property that is boolean, or do I have to stick to any kind of number format?

Comment: I am a little confused with the editing,  UIButton and CABasicAnimation is not being used as code, they are merely used to identify an item, why would they be marked with code tags

Comment: I don't now how to reach you but thank you very much. Your help with the classes did a lot. Lastly I had less time but in school we started a new project. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could have responded to my answer on your own question or just invited me to one of the chats on them LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the boolean. Well, it does, but not very much. It has to do with your whole animation. You're trying to animate something called "highlighted". That's meaningless.

Only layer properties are animatable with layer animation (CABasicAnimation), and not even all of those. Well, `"highlighted"` is *not* a layer property! (It isn't even a view property. It's a UIControl property.)

So there is nothing to animate. Your code has no effect. There is no runtime error, but nothing visible is going to happen.

Basically you need to just abandon this approach and find another way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Now that I know that the animation is only affected by the layer,  I was able to finally find some documentation on how the keypaths work,  for future reference:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html

Comment: The best explanation, IMNSHO, is still my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_the_animations_list

Comment: I was originally working with UIView.animationWithDuration, but that was only going from false to true and then stopping,  thanks for the input,  I will have to think of something else.  If all else fails, I will just use an NSTimer

Comment: You can make a custom animatable layer property, so that you do get interpolation (in whatever interpretation you give that). But the notion "highlighted", no matter you slice it, has no interpolation - the whole notion makes no sense. You cannot be "somewhat highlighted".

Comment: Yeah, I am merely doing it to get a flashing value going with the animation layer,  I do not want actual interpolation to happen, just off or on, anything inbetween is irrelevant

Comment: Why not use an animated image and set it as the button's image?

Comment: I plan on doing more then just altering an image,  that is why I would prefer altering the state